# Misplaced frames are again misplaced after updating frames and reopening project

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

I'm using storyboards and constraints on most or all the views in an app that's meant to run in portrait only. I lay out my views, update my frames to match my constraints, all is well, and I save and close the project. But when I open it again, many of the frames are out of place and I have to go through and update each one again. This is happening pretty consistently over time.

Three additional points:

1. When I first reopen the project, the number of warnings jumps to ~72, then settles down at around ~19, all of which are misplaced frame warnings that I corrected last time I had the project open.
2. I have the size classes bar set at Compact/Regular, which is possibly not optimal. But I'm afraid to change the setting in the middle of my project :D
3. Related to #2, the misplaced frame warnings all have to do with Xcode squeezing everything down to a narrower width. It seems to want to make everything fit within 240 width.

What can I do to make Xcode leave my frames in place after I update them? And how can I overcome my fear of changing the size classes settings?

Comment: Hi any solutions to this? I'm currently experiencing this and it is very annoying...